# How to discover BLE Profile / Handle in iOS (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, handle

I'm developing in Swift an iPhone Application and I'm working with CoreBluetooth.

The App works well to discover the services and characteristics but the problem is that I use the same service and characteristics twice. To do that in the other side (server side) we are using different BLE Profiles.

My question is: How do I discover the Profile/Handle from Services/Characteristics in Swift?

Best regards. =)

Comment: The only supported profile in Core Bluetooth is GATT. (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview) There is no access to any other profiles. Do you mean a different kind of profile than that?

Comment: Yeah @RobNapier, and GATT consists of the following:
**Profile**: this defines a specific use case and consists of a group of Services that satisfy the use case.
Service: a collection of data and associated behaviors to accomplish a specific feature or functionality.
Characteristic: contains a single value and optional information about the value.

E.g. When you use Heart Rate Service, the profile is Heart Rate Profile. But in my case we have 2 different BLE GATT Profiles on ESP32 with the same Service/Char. And if I don't recognize the profile, I won't know which one is sending the data

Comment: The bluetooth Profiles are not discoverable at a GATT level since they technically don't "exist". A profile is just a standardized collection of services that are needed for different purposes within a specific use-case. So if you wish to scan for a profile you just have to scan for the services within that profile. Technically a service could also belong to multiple profiles.